# JavaScript: What is the best way to skip a const

Tags: javascript

I want to skip block statement if it satisfied the condition.

```
const isJQuery = apps[key].technology === "jQuery";
```

//I want to skip isJQuery if below conditon is checked.

```
      if (!apps[key].aemSchema ) {
        additionalErrors.push(
          `There is no schema defined for ${key} (aka ${apps[key]})!`
        );
      } else if (!schemas[apps[key].aemSchema] ) {
        additionalErrors.push(
          `No schema ${key} (aka ${
            apps[key]
          })! Double check that it exists in  name ${
            apps[key].aemSchema
          }, and that the version included here is right.
          `found apps was `,
          apps
        );
      }
```

Any help would be helpful. 
I tried with

```
if (!apps[key].aemSchema || !isJQuery) { //code }
```

but this will always check first condition.

Comment: You can prepend `false &&` to any condition and the corresponding `if` block will always be skipped. For example `if (false && !apps[key].aemSchema) ...` - it's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you wanting to 'skip' the first if when isJQuery == true?

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. JS checks the values in an `if` condition as they're listed and if it hits a false, it exits the check and moves to the false condition.

Comment: @user633183 so what will be the code then ?
Is there any way i can skip it

Comment: @TonyAbrams yes i want to skip it.

Comment: @Lifz i just want to skip `JQuery` if it return true in if else condition.

Comment: I didn't get your issue, but you may use " label reference" with the break statement to exit blocks...

Comment: "i just want to skip `JQuery`" sorry, I don't know what this means with the code you've provided.

Comment: @Lifz thank you for your comment.
I want to check `const isJQuery = apps[key].technology === "jQuery";` if its true the in  my if else condition it will be skipped.

Comment: @AbdouBestmood how to do that ?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar as I said above, expressions in `if` statements are checked in the order you list them. If you use `&&` the first `false` condition will exit the `if`. If you use `||` the first `true` condition will exit the `if`.

Comment: else if (!schemas[apps[key].aemSchema] && !isJQuery )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments above, expressions in `if` statements are checked in the order you list them. If you use `&&` the first `false` condition will exit the `if`. If you use `||` the first `true` condition will exit the `if`. In your case, I would maybe just put an `if` on the first level of condition checking:

```
if (!isJquery) {
    // Other if/else statements inside
}
```